# How to add two webparts to different pages

Tags: web-part, powershell

I want to add two webparts to two different pages, using PowerShell

`Webpart1` to `sites/customers.aspx`

`Webpart2` to `sites/support.aspx`

```
$FullPageUrl = $SPWeb.Url + "/" + "sites" + "/customers.aspx"
```

This will only set 1 webpart to a page, but I also want to have `support.aspx`

```
$FullPageUrl = $SPWeb.Url + "/" + "sites" + "/support.aspx"
```

Could I maybe on some way set in my webpart the url were it should be deployed?

for example in my webpart:

`<url>customers.aspx</url> Webpart1`

`<url>support.aspx</url> Webpart2`

And then on some way set like this in powershell

```
$FullPageUrl = $SPWeb.Url + "/" + "sites" + "$url"
```